# Qt5 QMainWindow components deletion

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

One of our teacher asked us to create a Qt application without any UI file for the main window (a QMainWindow). Usually I always create one, leave it empty and let the *uic* deal with it.

I know that if a parental relation is defined between a widget (child) and its parent, then there is no need to delete the widget (deleted when the parent is deleted). So, when the UI is deleted, all the children are destroyed.

If we do not use an UI file (not generated), do we have to manually delete all the widget added to the GUI?

A little sample:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent){
     layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
     aButton = new QButton(this);
     layout->addWidget(aButton);
     ...
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui; // No need to delete more if parental relation.
    // However, what do we do if no ui has been generated?
    // Do we have to delete aButton?
}
```

The value of parent is 0. It is the main entry of the application.

Thanks

Comment: Its actually unclear what you're asking, but supposed `ui` is a `nullptr` `delete ui;` is a NOP. So it seems to be fine.

Comment: Well, I was asking about things that we have to do if we don't have an auto generated ui file. Do we have to manually delete each widget?

Comment: ***Do we have to manually delete each widget?*** No. The widgets should be children of the parent widget. QObject will handle them when the parent is deleted.

Comment: Yeah, but if the parent (MainWindow) does not have a parent and no ui file is generated?

Comment: It should have a parent QObject (or be on the stack or is manually deleted...) otherwise the MainWindow itself would have leaked.

Comment: ***and no ui file is generated*** Having a ui or not should not make a difference.

Comment: .ui files don't do anything magical, they get converted to C++ code which you could have written yourself (theoretically at least). Please check a generated *ui_XXX.h* of simple UI for some insight.

Comment: Another thing which will make your life a tiny bit easier: addWidget, setLayout etc reset the parent, so you don't need to give *this* as constructor parameter when you create widgets, layouts etc.

Comment: @hyde Yes, I know that it is the uic which translates the ui files into C++. But I thought that these ones represented also the "main parent" (QMainWindow in my case) of a widget, and when deleted, each child would be deleted. Simply confused, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [this article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html)

> QWidget, the fundamental class of the Qt Widgets module, extends the parent-child relationship. A child normally also becomes a child widget, i.e. it is displayed in its parent's coordinate system and is graphically clipped by its parent's boundaries. For example, when the application deletes a message box after it has been closed, the message box's buttons and label are also deleted, just as we'd want, because the buttons and label are children of the message box.

So, there is no difference do you use `ui` or not. When you delete window, all its children will be deleted too.